# SINR versus transmission rate

Tags: bandwidth

In the following paper on applications of Game Theory to power control in communications,

http://mackenab.ece.vt.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/mackenzie2001b.pdf

Why is the Signal to Interference and Noise Ratio (SINR) inversely proportional to the transmission rate R?

The expression for the SINR can be found in section III of the paper.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your power is fixed, then as you increase your bit rate, the energy per bit interval is decreased at the same rate. You can think of this as integrating the power over the length of the bit. If you integrate over less time, your energy for that bit will also be less. Specifically, if you double your rate, you cut your energy per bit in half. This is why the SINR is inversely proportional to the rate.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here with _power per bit interval_ being used in lieu of the term _bit energy_, the integral of the power over the bit duration. Doubling the bit rate does not cut the _power per bit_ in half, it cuts the _energy per bit_ in half. A 50-watt light bulb uses 50 watt-hours per hour; if you use it for 30 minutes, it is still a 50-watt bulb, not a 25-watt bulb.  Power and energy mean different things.... and power per bit is an abuse of nomenclature that is best avoided.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for the catch, I answered in a rush.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of a communication system depends to a great extent 
on E_b, the amount of *energy* received per bit. This energy
is the integral of the *instantaneous* (received) power per bit,
or, if you like, the *average power* over the bit duration times
the bit duration.  So, if the bit rate is increases, the bit
duration decreases and so does E_b.  Since SNR or SINR is the
ratio of the bit energy to the noise or interference-plus-signal
energy, the SNR and SINR decrease as the bit rate increases.

If you like to think in terms of power and bandwidth, and think
of SNR or SINR as the ratio of signal *power* to noise *power*
etc., then consider that decreasing the bit duration means 
using shorter pulses, and so more bandwidth is needed.  As a consequence,
there is more noise in the receiver since it needs to have
larger bandwidth to capture and process the wider-band signals.
Thus, while *signal power* remains fixed as the bit duration
decreases, the *noise power* increases, leading to the same
conclusion as before:

> As bit rate increases, SNR and SINR decrease.

Comment: can you please clarify why: _decreasing the bit duration means (using shorter pulses, and so) more bandwidth is needed?_. I fail to visualize that in my head...

Comment: @KristofTak Consider the Fourier spectrum of a pulse of short duration versus a (similar) pulse of longer duration. Which has more content at high frequencies? If the channel does not have enough bandwidth, the short pulse will be smeared out in time and give rise to _inter-symbol interference_ which brings in additional complications that need to be taken into account.